# autocomplete jQuery display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm learning jQuery and i would like to use autocomplete. But i don't know why my data don't display in my html. Can you explain me what's wrong in this source code please.

```
<?php 
// receive data
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']));          // protection
    require_once('../required.php');
    //our request
    $rslt= $pdoSearch->findCity($q);
    $tab=array();
    foreach ($rslt as $data){
        array_push($tab,
            array(
                "label" => $data['fistname']." ".$data['lastname']." ".$data['login']." ".$data['mdp']." ".$data['city'],
                "value" => $data['id']
            )
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($tab);
} ?>
```

My autocomplete file :

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: 'fichier.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $("#id").val();
    });     
});
```

And my HTML file :

```
<fieldset  id="field" >
    <legend>Fonctionnalit&eacute;s</legend><br />
    <form class="icon" method="get">
        <label for="search">Recherche: </label>
        <input id="id" name="id" hidden="hidden" />
        <input type="text" id="search" style="width: 600px;"/>
        <input type="submit" id="button"/>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards,

EDIT : I found my problem, it was i'm using an other id with the same name in my html.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

missed space `' '` in between `as` in foreach

```
foreach ($rslt as $data){
           //-^^---here
```

Comment: Hi thanks but that doesn't work anyway, i just failed in my copy/paste :/

Answer (score 0):

Use autocomple jquery plugin
http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

add `js`  files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

input box

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="query" />
```

Javascript

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function(){
   options = { serviceUrl:'your service' };
   a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
});
```

Retun data formate

```
{
query:'Li',
suggestions:['Liberia', 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', 'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania'],
data:['LR', 'LY', 'LI', 'LT']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure your php returns a well formed json by controlling the result of the fichier.php file. Display it to control its content.

Then, your data aren't displayed because your input is hidden. remove the hidden attribut to show the field :

```
<input id="id" name="id" type="text" />
```

And for your autocomplete element, there is no need to use the

```
$("#search").val(ui.item.label);
```

This should behave automatically when selecting the item you want. Here is an exemple:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
      source: 'fichier.php',
      autoFocus: true,
      minLength: 2, //minimum 2 chars to execute an autocomplete
      select: function (event,ui) {        
          $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
return false;
          }
        });
```

Comment: N.B : to have the autocomplete element, you need jQueryUI, not only jQuery